# I have an aspx page with master page and i want to asynchronous update the ContantPlaceHolder

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an aspx page with master page and i want to asynchronous update the ContantPlaceHolder, i think about apdate panel, when the user submit the actions the update panel will close and open again with the solution, or to use an:

ContentPlaseHolder.Controls.Add(FormView);

I want the content in the place holder will display the existing aspx page and run its code behind.

Every body have an idea how to do this if its possible?
(If it is possible with AJAX is fine)

Comment: What is the issue if you put your ContentPlaceHolder within an `UpdatePanel`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/